# To find exact name from the list in a bash file

Tags: bash, grep

I have following data file in bash. I want to search if the user entered webserver is present in the data file, if present it should return the Phase and Managed server name.

```
1 K1 tvtw1 tvtm1
1 K1 tvtw2 tvtw2
2 K2 tvtw26 tvtw26
3 k5 tvtw29 tvtm29
```

I tried `grep "$webserver" serverList.lst | awk '{print $1}'` but it returns multiple values for tvtw2. Is there any way to find exact server name from the list ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, if column 3 matches exactly, then you want to get the value of column 1:

```
awk -v serv=tvtw2 '$3 == serv {print $1}' serverList.lst
```

That is, we put the string you want to match in variable `serv`, and then use that as a filter expression in `awk` to match column 3 exactly.

Answer (score 0):

you need add word boundary in your grep regex, so that `tvtw26` won't be selected.

e.g. `grep '\btvtw2\b' file ...`

However since you have already used awk, you can consider to use awk for all. @janos 's answer showed how could it be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try `grep -w` (`-w` stands for word regex)

However, `grep | awk` is [useless-use-of-grep](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep). See janos's answer for more optimal solution.